# bootstrap 2.3.2 tooltip not working in rails + haml

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm trying to add tooltips to my app, so far I got to this:

```
.span1
  ID
  =link_to "?", "#", rel: "tooltip", title: "Order Number"
  = order.id
```

That generates this HTML:

```
 <div class="span1">ID<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Order Number">?</a>...</div>
```

I would like to obtain a ID? string where if the user hoovers on the `?` he sees the tooltip. With this nothing happens, and if I click I reload the page. 
Although inspecting the dom I see that when I hoover on the `?`, there's a

```
<div class="tooltip fade top in" ....
```

being generated. unfortunately the div disappears when I hoover off the mouse, so I can't expand the div to see what's inside.

bootstrap is fairly loaded, and it works correctly on the other things (scaffolding, collapsible etc...)

My `bootstrap.js.coffee` reads:

```
jQuery ->
  $("a[rel=popover]").popover()
  $(".tooltip").tooltip()
  $("a[rel=tooltip]").tooltip()
```

any clues?

thanks,

UPDATE:

I managed to get some of the tooltips to work, but not all:

```
  %a{rel: "tooltip", title: "Expand"}
    %span.icon-plus{data: {toggle: "collapse", target: "\##{order_id}"}}
  = link_to edit_order_path(order), rel: "tooltip", title: "Edit Order" do
    %span.icon-edit
  = link_to order_path(order), rel: "tooltip", title: "Delete", method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do
    %span.icon-remove
```

the first two links have tooltips, the third has no tooltip. I believe it has to do with the fact that the `method: :delete` parameter adds the `nofollow` into the `rel` and this breaks the tooltip. 
Any clue about how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a solution or a workaround, I've managed to get it to work by adding to `bootstrap.js.coffee` the following:

```
$("span[rel=tooltip]").tooltip()
```

and changed the last link definition to:

```
= link_to order_path(order), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do
  %span.icon-remove.idrow{rel: "tooltip", title: "Delete"}
```

I now see the tooltips also on the link that has ajax calls in it.